# How can I rsync and set some files as gzipped, using Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

We are using Google Cloud Storage and the `gsutil` command. We'd like to rsync a large directory with many text files, and we'd like *some* of those files to be compressed and have their Content-Encoding set to gzip. It looks like we can only set Content-Encoding (using `-h`) for *all* files when using `gsutil rsync`, which is a bummer. Some of our files are images, which we do not want compressed.

Alternatively, we'd like to run an rsync in *only delete from the destination what is no longer on the source* mode. We don't want to also upload. We just want to delete from GCS what is no longer in our local source directory. However, I didn't find that option.

Answer (score 3):

The gsutil rsync command doesn't support an option to compress files while uploading (i.e., something analogous to the gsutil cp -z option). We considered adding such an option but it would create a lot of complexity and potentially surprising behavior (e.g, when synchronizing against objects that had been uploaded using gsutil cp -z).

Also, I don't think manually setting the Content-Encoding the way you stated in your second paragraph would work the way you're expecting. Doing something like:

```
gsutil -h Content-Encoding:gzip rsync ...
```

would result in the object not being gzipped but still having the Content-Encoding metadata set -- which would then confuse user agents (like browsers) that act on the Content-Encoding header when downloading.

Have you considered compressing the files you want compressed, at the source? If you can't leave those files compressed at the source, could you write a shell script that copies everything to a temp directory, compresses the files you want compressed, and then runs gsutil rsync from there?